# How to declare ambient typescript class for an NPM package prototype object?

Tags: typescript

I have an NPM package that has an object as follows:

```
const Lipsum = function constructor(argOne, argTwo) {
...
}

Object.assign(Lipsum.prototype, {
    firstMethod: function firstMethod(firstArg, secondArg){...}
    secondMethod: function secondMethod(){}
})

module.exports = Lipsum;
```

I want to declare an ambient TypeScript class for it. I've created a file in my project `shared/lipsum.d.ts` and wrote the following:

```
declare class Lipsum {
    constructor(argOne: string, argTwo: number)

    firstMethod(firstArg: string, secondArg: string): string
    secondMethod(): void
}

export default Lipsum;
```

I'm facing the following issue:

```
const x = new Lipsum(); // <--- this doesn't throw an error, even though the constructor must have two arguments.
x. // <--- It doesn't autocomplete here, but it autocompletes above when I put a dot after "Lipsum()".
```

Update:

I attempted to wrap the class with a module declaration, like so:

```
declare module 'lipsum'{
    export default class Lipsum {
        constructor(argOne: string, argTwo: number)

        firstMethod(firstArg: string, secondArg: string): string
        secondMethod(): void
    }
}
```

It keeps telling me:

> Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'lipsum' resolves to an untyped module at '/Users/yaharga/project/node_modules/lipsum/lipsum.js', which cannot be augmented.

I should note the code is in a file 'lipsum.d.ts' already.

Turns out all the imports need to be inside the "declare module" scope. Thanks to [@drag13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60398858/1934402) for pointing me in the right direction.

For more information regarding the error I was getting, I used [this post](https://exceptionshub.com/having-error-module-name-resolves-to-an-untyped-module-at-when-writing-custom-typescript-definition-file.html) for reference.

Comment: Note that your file `shared/lipsum.d.ts` may as well not be a `.d.ts` file because as soon as you `export` or `import` anything, it becomes a "module" type instead of a "script" type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the module your typing related to.  Just add module definition like here

```
declare module 'MODULE_NAME' {
   class Lipsum {
        constructor(argOne: string, argTwo: number)

        firstMethod(firstArg: string, secondArg: string): string
        secondMethod(): void
    }

    export default Lipsum;
}
```

Comment: It keeps telling me Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'lipsum' resolves to an untyped module at '/Users/jondoe/project/node_modules/lipsum/lipsum.js', which cannot be augmented.

Comment: Great to see you found the solution.